# Python plotly write_html: Integrate graph into a new page with additional content

Tags: python, html, plotly

I would like to integrate a plotly graph into a html page. This is working so far, as I can create a page with `write_html` and create a new html file, that only includes the graph. 
Further I try to integrate that graph into another html page to make it part of a page, so I added it with `<script src="example_plot.html"></script>` into an existing html file with more text, but it always goes full page when I open the new page. I tried to change the autosizing, width, height etc., nothing worked.
I am grateful for every help, thanks a lot in advance. Cheers!

creating plotly graph and html page:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=x**2))

fig.write_html('example_graph.html')
```

embedding plotly graph into another html page: unfortunately always full screen and not part of page, additional content is not shown:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Plotly and fun </title>
</head>

<h1>Title and some content above plotly graph</h1>

<div src="example_graph.html"></div>

<p>Other stuff below the plot</p>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the html that was generated by the write_html function (i.e. open the 'example_graph.html' file with a text editor) and copy paste that in your original webpage. Works fine with graph_objects library as well.
You can see that the 'example_graph.html' file starts with `<div> <script type=...> <...>`.
Simply embed that code in your original web page.

As the 'include_plotlyjs' argument is set to True by default in the write_html function, the plotly.js library (approx. 3 MB) is included with the html and the new web page is therefore OS agnostic, provided that the browser that opens the new page has support for java(script) which most common browsers always have.